# Using sed, write portions of the line below a specific string to two different variables

Tags: regex, linux, sed, text-processing

I have text files that contain the following, with 'DOB' only mentioned once in the file....

```
DOB
Female 1/1/1963
```

In the example listed, I need to store Female in a variable called VarGender, and the date in a field called VarDOB.  I'd like to end up with...

```
VarGender=Female
VarDOB=1/1/1963
```

The following will return the whole line below DOB.  I could use some help in getting each half of the line into the right variable.

```
sed -n '/DOB/{n;p}' file.txt
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify buffer before printing it:

```
$ sed -n '/DOB/{n;s/^\([^ ]\+\).*/\1/;p}' file.txt
Female
$ sed -n '/DOB/{n;s/^[^ ]\+ \(.*\)/\1/;p}' file.txt
1/1/1963
```

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory `awk` alternative:

```
awk '! /DOB/ { printf "VarGender=%s\nVarDOB=%s\n",$1,$2 }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ read; read VarGender VarDOB; } < file.txt
```

This would read it somewhere in the file:

```
while P=$VarGender; read VarGender VarDOB && [[ $P != DOB ]]; do :; done < file.txt
```

Comment: Or pipe the sed command into the second read if DOB... is not on the first two lines of the file.

Comment: @ooga Calling `sed` is not necessary :) And you'd need process substitution for that since reading from a pipe would store variables on a subshell.

Comment: I may have confused matters.  I don't want to literally output VarGender=Female; I want a variable $VarGender to contain the value 'Female'.  Thank you.

Comment: @konsolebox I guess I don't understand how the first answer provides what I want.

Comment: @raparks It redirects input from file as a block. `read` reads input line by line. so the first instance reads the first line, and the second instance the reads the second line which splits it to the two variables VarGender and VarDOB. You can read more info about the command with `help read`.

Comment: @konsolebox How does it know to specifically look for the line following DOB only?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this while loop:

```
while read -r line; do
    [[ "$line" == "DOB" ]] && dob=1 && continue
    ((dob==1)) && dob=0 && read VarGender VarDOB <<< "$line"
done < file

echo "$VarGender :: $VarDOB"
Female :: 1/1/1963
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler while loop.

```
while read field1 therest; do
  if [ ${field1:-x} = DOB ]; then
    read VarGender VarDOB;
    break;
  fi;
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ arr=( $(awk 'f{print; exit} /DOB/{f=1}' file) )
$ VarGender="${arr[0]}"
$ VarDOB="${arr[1]}"
$ echo "$VarGender"
Female
$ echo "$VarDOB"
1/1/1963
```